# Stream Windows 8 audio to Apple TV

Tags: windows-8, audio, streaming, appletv

I want to stream music from my Windows 8.1 laptop to my Apple TV device (which is connected to my home stereo). 
The only program i can find is [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/), which should be able to stream both audio and video. But i cant get audio to work, so this piece of software is pretty useless to me.

Are there any other options? Preferably audio-only?

Comment: Why not use iTunes for this?

Comment: Because i mainly use Spotify for playing music.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mac it can be done through mirroring. You should not need a third party app.

http://store.apple.com/us_smb_78313/question/answers/appletv/can-i-use-the-spotify-app-through-apple-tv/QUCKKHDT2KP9CCAHU

Here is an article about setting it up:
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5404

Comment: I'm not running a Mac, but Windows 8.1.